# Show sum of childs per parent in Angular table

Tags: angular

I would like to calculate a sum of childs per row in an Angular (6) table. A dish has ingredients which have a price. This price I want to sum up per dish.

The Angular table only shows the sum of the first parent, for all the parents. I guess due to **return total**. 
When I remove **return total**, a console.log shows the right output per parent. 
When I put "return total" one bracket below, it only shows the final parent's sum.

How can I ensure Angular gives the output per parent? (so, continue the loop and print the right output per row)? Thanks in advance!

```
 calcPrice() {

    for (let dish of this.dishes) {

      let total = 0;

      for (let ingredient of dish.ingredients) {
        total += ingredient.pricePerUnit;

      }
      return total;
    }
  }
```

html:

```
<tr *ngFor='let dish of dishes'>
  <td>{{ calcPrice() }}</td>
```

Comment: Remove the `for` loop from `calcPrice`, and instead pass in the `dish`, using `{{calcPrice(dish)}}`

Comment: thanks, I will try it out. But what will the code of calcPrice then be?

Comment: I actually provided an answer earlier, but it was pointed out that calling a function from the template is very inefficient. It would be better to loop through the dishes, and add a `total` property to each dish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a one-liner for that with `reduce`.

Example in JS :

```js
const dishes = [
  { name: 'Chicken Parm', ingredients: [
    { name: 'Soy sauce', price: 2, amount: 200 },
    { name: 'Chiken', price: 5, amount: 150 },
    { name: 'Parmigiano Regiano', price: 8, amount: 50 },
    { name: 'Olive oil', price: 1.5, amount: 10 },
  ]}
];

function dishPrice(dish) {
  return dish.ingredients.reduce((p, n) => p + n.price, 0);
}

console.log(`Expected : 2+5+8+1.5=${2+5+8+1.5}, Got ${dishPrice(dishes[0])}`);
```

[`Reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) is a Javascript function that will iterate over each item, and in the end, return a single value.

The signature is

```
reduce(callback(previousElement, nextElement), firstValue);
```

*(The `previousElement` being the `firstValue` on the first item)*

Comment: Great, this works. Thanks as well for the explanation of reduce!